# Build SoX with LAME support in Cygwin

Tags: build, open-source, cygwin, sox, lame

I'm trying to build SoX (14.4.1) in Cygwin with MP3 support using LAME (3.99.5). I've been following this guide: http://bencos.googlecode.com/svn-history/r137/trunk/out/sox/README.win32.txt
When running "./configure" it tells me that it "cannot find LAME". I have put lame-enc.dll in the sox directory, but it's not detected. Can anyone help me to figure out why this fails? Here's the command and the output from the log file:

```
./configure --with-lame

...
configure:13645: checking whether to dlopen lame
configure:13654: result: no
configure:13664: checking lame/lame.h usability
configure:13664: gcc -c -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -W -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic -fopenmp  conftest.c >&5
configure:13664: $? = 0
configure:13664: result: yes
configure:13664: checking lame/lame.h presence
configure:13664: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:13664: $? = 0
configure:13664: result: yes
configure:13664: checking for lame/lame.h
configure:13664: result: yes
configure:13689: checking for lame_get_lametag_frame in -lmp3lame
configure:13714: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -W -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic -fopenmp   conftest.c -lmp3lame   >&5
conftest.c:53:1: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
conftest.c:55:1: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmp3lame
```

**Edit**: I got *configure* and *make* working by installing several packages in cygwin and updating the path. The pro tip is to read the install files to see if they list required packages and possibly check the Linux distributions, because their packages refer to dependencies and build dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need `--enable-dl-lame` as well so that it will use the dynamic library:

```
./configure --with-lame --enable-dl-lame
```

**Edit** to incorporate information from the comment discussion:

More Cygwin packages may be required, such as `libltdl` and `libtool-*` (for dynamic loading support), zlib-related packages (for *libid3tag*) etc.

Also, `configure.ac` needs patching (change `*mingw*)` to `*cygwin* | *mingw*)` in line 175), then the `configure` script has to be regenerated via `autoreconf` (`gcc-tools` Cygwin package). Alternatively, you could try to find the line in `configure` that corresponds to `configure.ac` line 175 and change that; regenerating isn’t necessary in that case.

Comment: Ok I tried it. The only thing that changed was these rows, failed the same way as in the log in original post.

    configure:13645: checking whether to dlopen lame
    configure:13654: result: yes

Comment: Then I guess you don’t have `libltdl` support for whatever reason, possibly because configure only checks for the host triplet to contain `*mingw*`. Do you have autotools (`autoreconf` etc.) available? If so, try changing line 175 in `configure.ac` from `*mingw*)` to `*cygwin* | *mingw*)`, then run `autoreconf` and try again.

Comment: I installed libltdl7 and gcc-tools (autoreconf). Now "configure" finishes successfully, but make fails: cannot find ltdl.h

Comment: It seems ltdl.h is contained in one of the libtool Cygwin packages, not in libltdl7: http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=ltdl.h

Comment: Slow progress, but progress nonetheless. I installed the package and make fails with this line: "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lz"

Comment: OK. :) Otherwise, `-lz` means _zlib_ (a compression library used by _libid3tag_ and _libpng_). If you don’t need those, you could deactivate them via `--without-id3tag --without-png`; or install the _zlib_ Cygwin packages.

Comment: Didn't work, could be a path issue or that I installed the wrong version :(   But what I really need to learn is how to work when building source. Is there a way to find out what packages I need in advance, what documentation to read etc.

Comment: SoX in particular has a list of the optional libraries in its `INSTALL` file. (_zlib_ is not listed because it should come automatically with _libpng_ … usually.) Otherwise a good source of information can be Linux distributions, because their packages refer to dependencies and build dependencies. I don’t have experience with Cygwin however, I never use Windows at all.

Answer (score 1):

The `zlib-devel` package provides the library necessary for -lz.

Comment: Thanks! That was the last package, I was able to compile everything now.